# W3C HTML in JavaScript  validation

Tags: javascript, w3c

I have JavaScript  in my template file, because of the smarty can't include the file and I have W3C problem validation:

```
addMarker({$item->lat}, {$item->lng}, '<div style="height: 280px;">dfdsfsd</div>');
```

Error element not allowed.

Is there a way to escape it somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split the start-tag and end-tag open delimiters:

```
addMarker({$item->lat}, {$item->lng}, '<'+'div style="height: 280px;">dfdsfsd<'+'/div>');
```

Or replace them by escape sequences:

```
addMarker({$item->lat}, {$item->lng}, '\x3Cdiv style="height: 280px;">dfdsfsd\x3C/div>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Better split it '<d' + 'iv and also the end tag otherwise you'll get an "end tag without start tag" error.